# on click radio button change select value only html css

Tags: html, forms, validation, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" id="carform" name="radioForm">
        <input type="radio" name="fname" id="Volvo:" value="volvo">
        <label for="Volvo:">Volvo:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="fname" id="Saab:" value="saab">
        <label for="Saab:">Saab:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="fname" id="Opel:" value="opel">
        <label for="Opel:">Opel:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="fname" id="Audi:" value="audi">
        <label for="Audi:">Audi:</label>
        <br/>
        <select  form="carform" id="select">
            <option name="fname" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option name="fname" value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option name="fname" value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option name="fname" value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
<script>
var rad = document.radioForm.fname;
var prev = null;
for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onclick = function() {
        if(this !== prev) {
            prev = this;
        }
        console.log(this.value);
        document.getElementById('select').value=this.value;
    };
}
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

whenever I click on `radio button` input type, select value is changing, this I have done using javascript. Can anyone help me to do same thing without javascript, jquery and all? Only using html, css.

Comment: No, even checkbox hack will not help in this case. And after all, WHY would you do it? This is exact reason (page interactivity) why javascript is invented....

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with HTML and CSS. HTML is a markup language and CSS is styling the HTML. They don't provide any thing for event base programming. You need to use jquery/javascript for event base programming.

Comment: markup language ok,but whenever i click on the label tag it radio button is selecting,samething  whenever i click on the  radio button select input has to change

Comment: This done with `for` attribute and its common need for all forms.

Comment: we can do it by using id's and input names,same thing i am trying if i find answer i will update

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that using javascript not possible with Html. use react for virtual DOM. Or you can do it simply by using simple JS or jquery.

Comment: markup language ok,but whenever i click on the label tag it radio button is selecting,samething whenever i click on the radio button select input has to change

Comment: Brother Virtual DOM is concept of ReactJs as name suggest it is a js liberary,., You need to uderstand one basic concept, that is Html is static laguage it only run's once and attach events to the Dom object,., it can not change it self on run time ,., you have to take help from some js library or JS itself as you are doing right now.

Comment: we can do it by using id's and input names,same thing i am trying if i find answer i will update

Comment: i think you are confusing it with angularJS two way binding ,. but please do let me know if you find a way to do that ,.,